# Use data from local system in my kubernetes Pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I want to use data from the files present in my localsystem in my pod in k8s.
How is PersistentLocalVolumes used in this and is it safe to use PersistentLocalVolumes as it is an alpha feature.

Thanks

Comment: It's an alpha feature so I suggest to read up on [maturity levels of the API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) for guidance on what you can expect. Also, did you read the following resource: https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/local-volume

Answer (score 4):

For cluster created with kubeadm.

### /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf

Add a line for KUBE_FEATURE_GATES.

```
Environment="KUBE_FEATURE_GATES=--feature-gates PersistentLocalVolumes=true,VolumeScheduling=true,MountPropagation=true"
```

Add $KUBE_FEATURE_GATES to the ExecStart line.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_SYSTEM_PODS_ARGS $KUBELET_NETWORK_ARGS $KUBELET_DNS_ARGS $KUBELET_AUTHZ_ARGS $KUBELET_CADVISOR_ARGS $KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS $KUBELET_CERTIFICATE_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS $KUBE_FEATURE_GATES
```

### Manifest

```
$ cat local_pvc.yaml

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-local-pv
  annotations:
    "volume.alpha.kubernetes.io/node-affinity": '{
      "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
        "nodeSelectorTerms": [
          { "matchExpressions": [
            { "key": "kubernetes.io/hostname",
              "operator": "In",
              "values": ["my-node"]  <--- change the node name to yours
            }
          ]}
         ]}
        }'
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi  <----- change the size to your need
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /mnt/disks/vol1  <----- change the path to yours

---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: example-local-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi  <----- change the size to your need
  storageClassName: local-storage

----
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

### Execution

1. Restart the cluster.
2. Create the pv & pvc (kubectl create -f local_pvc.yaml).
3. Use the pvc in the pod.

### References

- [doc: update with Kubernetes localhost persistent storage example](https://github.com/juju-solutions/bundle-canonical-kubernetes/issues/369)
- [Feature Gates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/feature-gates/)
- [Kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubelet/) (see
  feature gate parameter such as **PersistentLocalVolumes=true**)
- [Local Persistent Storage User Guide](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/local-volume)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [hostPath Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath), which will allow you to mount a directory from the host filesystem onto the POD.